# cross-referencing in the appendix, imsart package

Tags: appendix, section-titles

I have a problem running the following code, which uses imsart package and aop option:

```
\documentclass[aop]{imsart}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm}
    This is a Theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{appendix}
\section{Proof to Theorem \ref{thm}}
Proof of Theorem \ref{thm}
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

The outcome is this:[image]

it fails to add the hyperlink to the theorem in the title of the appendix. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `\appendix`, `\section` is redefined to apply `\MakeUppercase` to each title, which has the unfortunate consequence of uppercasing also `thm`.

Indeed, you get

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `THM' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.
```

You can work around the issue by loading `textcase` with the `overload` option, that will avoid `\MakeUppercase` touching the argument to `\ref`.

```latex
\documentclass[aop]{imsart}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase} % <---- added
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm}
    This is a Theorem.
\end{theorem}

\appendix
\section{Proof to Theorem \ref{thm}}
Proof of Theorem \ref{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, there is no `appendix` environment defined. Just the `\appendix` *declaration*.

Comment: The perfect answer, thank you!